# DELETE statement deleting data partially

Tags: db2, sql-delete

When I am executing a below query in DB2 it is not deleting data at once.

I have got 800 records and out of that every 2 records are duplicate and I want to delete 1 record of 2 records so it will leave 400 records in DB.

Below is a sample of RESERVATION_NUMBER.

[image]

```
DELETE 
FROM   reservation_number 
WHERE  reservation_id IN (SELECT reservation_id 
                          FROM   (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
                                           OVER() AS RN, 
                                         msr1.reservation_number, 
                                         msr1.reservation_id, 
                                         msr1.used_flag 
                                  FROM   reservation_number msr1, 
                                         reservation_number msr2 
                                  WHERE 
              msr1.reservation_number = msr2.reservation_number 
              AND msr1.reservation_id <> msr2.reservation_id 
                                  ORDER  BY msr1.reservation_number) 
                          WHERE  Mod (rn, 2) = 0 
                          ORDER  BY reservation_number)
```

This query is deleting complete data if I execute it multiple time. Data is being deleted in below fashion -

400, 168, 076, 038, 019, 003, 001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this not be easier?

```
DELETE FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY RESERVATION_NUMBER 
                             ORDER BY     RESERVATION_ID     ) AS RN
    FROM
        RESERVATION_NUMBER
) WHERE RN > 1
```

Comment: Yes. :-). I was using a self-join. This one is better.

Answer (score 0):

I got the fix. I was missing a parameter in  OVER().

Here is the right query

```
DELETE
FROM
    RESERVATION_NUMBER
WHERE
    RESERVATION_ID IN (
    SELECT
        RESERVATION_ID
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY msr1.RESERVATION_NUMBER) AS RN,
            msr1.RESERVATION_NUMBER,
            msr1.RESERVATION_ID,
            msr1.USED_FLAG
        FROM
            RESERVATION_NUMBER msr1 ,
            RESERVATION_NUMBER msr2
        WHERE
            msr1.RESERVATION_NUMBER = msr2.RESERVATION_NUMBER
            AND msr1.RESERVATION_ID <> msr2.RESERVATION_ID
        ORDER BY
            msr1.RESERVATION_NUMBER )
    WHERE
        MOD (RN,2)=1 
    ORDER BY
        RESERVATION_NUMBER )
```